# Positioning a UILabel directly beneath another UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, sizetofit

I have an addition to `NSString` which automatically resizes a `UILabel` depending on the text that's being read into it (I have a simple app showing quotations, so some are a few words, some a couple sentences). Below that `quote` label, I also have an `author` label, which (oddly enough) has the author of the quote in it.

I'm trying to position that `author` label directly beneath the `quote` label (as in, its `y` coordinate would be the `quote` label's `y` coordinate plus the `quote` label's `height`. What I'm seeing is some space being placed between the two labels, that depending on the length of the quote, changes size. Smaller quotes have more space, while longer quotes have less space. Here's a quick diagram of what I'm seeing:

[image]
[image]

Note the gap between the red and blue boxes (which I've set up using `layer.borderColor/borderWidth` so I can see them in the app), is larger the shorter the quote is.

If anyone can sift through the code below and help point me towards exactly what's causing the discrepancy, I'd be really grateful. From what I can see, the `author` label should always be 35 pixels beneath the `quote` label's `y + height` value.

Just to confirm: everything is hooked up correctly in Interface Builder, etc. The content of the quote's getting in there fine, everything else works, so it's hooked up, that isn't the issue.

To clarify, my question is: **Why is the gap between the labels changing dependant on the quote's length, and how can I get a stable, settable gap of 35 pixels correctly?**

Here's the code I'm using to position the labels:

```
// Fill and format Quote Details
_quoteLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", _selectedQuote.quote];
_authorLabel.text = _selectedQuote.author;
[_quoteLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: kScriptFont size: 28.0f]];
[_authorLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: kScriptFontAuthor size: 30.0f]];

// Automatically resize the label, then center it again.
[_quoteLabel sizeToFitMultipleLines];
[_quoteLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(11, 11, 298, _quoteLabel.frame.size.height)];

// Position the author label below the quote label, however high it is.
[_authorLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(11, 11 + _quoteLabel.frame.size.height + 35, _authorLabel.frame.size.width, _authorLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

Here's my custom method for `sizeToFitMultipleLines`:

```
- (void) sizeToFitMultipleLines
{
    if (self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) {
        CGFloat adjustedFontSize = [self.text fontSizeWithFont: self.font constrainedToSize: self.frame.size minimumFontSize: self.minimumScaleFactor];
        self.font = [self.font fontWithSize: adjustedFontSize];
    }
    [self sizeToFit];
}
```

And here's my `fontSizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:minimumFontSize:` method:

```
- (CGFloat) fontSizeWithFont: (UIFont *) font constrainedToSize: (CGSize) size minimumFontSize: (CGFloat) minimumFontSize
{
    CGFloat fontSize = [font pointSize];
    CGFloat height = [self sizeWithFont: font constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    UIFont *newFont = font;

    // Reduce font size while too large, break if no height (empty string)
    while (height > size.height && height != 0 && fontSize > minimumFontSize) {
        fontSize--;
        newFont = [UIFont fontWithName: font.fontName size: fontSize];
        height = [self sizeWithFont: newFont constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    };

    // Loop through words in string and resize to fit
    for (NSString *word in [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]) {
        CGFloat width = [word sizeWithFont: newFont].width;
        while (width > size.width && width != 0 && fontSize > minimumFontSize) {
            fontSize--;
            newFont = [UIFont fontWithName: font.fontName size: fontSize];
            width = [word sizeWithFont: newFont].width;
        }
    }
    return fontSize;
}
```

Comment: Where does the red and blue boxes come from? Are they they frames of the labels? Also, `CGRectGetMaxY()` etc. are a nice functions that you should have a look at.

Comment: In your example-code you just adjust the fontsize to fit in the label, but where are you define the `_quoteLabel.frame.size.height`?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist The red and blue boxes are set up using `layer.borderColor/borderWidth` of the labels themselves, so they are accurately showing the frame of the label.

Comment: @xapslock I don't set the height explicitly, I calculate the font size needed to fit the text in the label, then `sizeToFit`.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist setting the `author`'s Y coordinate to `CGRectGetMaxY()` causes it to overlap the `quote`, not sit directly below it. It overlaps by a different amount depending on the size of the quote, too, so it's the same issue, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you called size to fit on both labels, calculate the distance between their frames and change them accordingly:

```
[quoteLabel sizeToFit];
[authorLabel sizeToFit];

float distance = authorLabel.frame.origin.y - quoteLabel.frame.size.height;
float difference = distance - 35;

authorLabel.frame = CGRectMake(authorLabel.frame.origin.x,(authorLabel.frame.origin.y - difference),authorLabel.frame.size.width,authorLabel.frame.size.height);
```

The reason the gap changes is that the quote label frame changes its height dependent on its content when you call sizeToFit.

**UPDATE**

Given the recent developments in the comments, I think you have 3 possibilities:

- resize the whitespace instead of only the words, so that the string
  actually fits in the frame correctly
- somehow access the CTFramesetter of UILabel to see what the actual
  frame, when all is said and done, amounts to
- make your own UIView subclass that handles Core Text drawing in its
  draw rect method (should be easy in your case), since after all you
  are trying to give to UILabel a behavior that it's not meant for

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked at all, it's made no difference to what I'm seeing. The `distance` and `difference` floats always report as `46` and `11` respectively, no matter what length of quote I select.

Comment: does the same thing happen when you leave the font sizing alone?

Comment: That's a good question.. checking.. no, the `author` is in a stable place just a couple of pixels beneath the `quote` when I comment out the call to `sizeToFitMultipleLines`.

Comment: what size is your minimum font size? Also I see you are passing minimumScaleFactor as minimum font size: minimum font size = minimum scale factor * normal size.

Comment: also, I don't know if it's related to your problem, but why if you are resizing the font the two screenshots have the same font size? And what is the default quote label height? is it shorter or taller then the one of the label in the first screenshot?

Comment: The screenshots themselves aren't from my UI, they're just a representation, but they're virtually the same as the app itself. The default quote label height is around two thirds of the view (around 290px high). I'm only changing the font if the quote is longer than the maximum allowable height of the label (which is that 290px height). If it fits in there, I don't reduce the font size.

Comment: so you are calling fontSizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:minimumFontSize: only for the 1st case but for the second you are not? did you check minimum scale factor as I said above?

Comment: I'm calling that method for the `quote`, there's no need to call it for the `author` since that's just a single line. Sorry, missed the other comment there, the minimum scale factor set in IB for the `quote` label is 0.5.

Comment: so you are passing the minimum scale factor instead of the minimum font size to - (CGFloat) fontSizeWithFont: (UIFont *) font constrainedToSize: (CGSize) size minimumFontSize: (CGFloat) minimumFontSize. Tell me what happens when you fix that

Comment: `minimumFontSize` is actually deprecated in iOS6, hadn't noticed that before. I've put a hard-coded value of 14.0f in there, and it's made no difference at all again, I'm afraid :(

Comment: well that was going to be a problem too though :-) . Anyway I think the  gap does not change with the frame size per se, but with whether you are calling the resizing method. Maybe the frame property does not get updated correctly, especially because I see that you are resizing the words but not the white space between the words.

Comment: That's true. I wonder if there's any other reference point I can use to position the `author` a set distance below the bottom of the `quote`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I wrote my closing thoughts in the answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by resize the white space – I'm resizing the label to the smallest it can be while still containing the text. What whitespace is there, asides from that between the lines, which I don't think I have any control over?

Answer (score 1):

It probably is moving where you want it, but then an auto-layout constraint or a spring/strut is moving it afterwards.

**EDIT:**
My **first** thought (which I ruled out because you said that the box around the words was the label frame.  In later comments, you say that this is not an actual screen shot, but just a representation of it, so it could still be correct) was that you are doing this wrong:

```
[_quoteLabel sizeToFitMultipleLines];
[_quoteLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(11, 11, 298, _quoteLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

In the first line, you are sizing the text to fit in whatever the current width of the label might be, and then you turn around in the second line and change the width of the label.  So most likely, what is happening is that you are sizing the label for some smaller width, which makes it tall.  You then make the label wider than it was before and the text expands to fit the wider label, leaving a blank area beneath the actual text, although the frame has not changed.  This makes the space betwee the labels exactly 35 as you want, however the top label's text does not go all of the way to the bottom of its frame so the white space is more than you want.  Basically, you have this:

```
*************
* text text *
* text text *
*           *
*           *
*           *
*************

*************
* text text *
*************
```

If this is the case, then you would fix it by setting the width first, like this:

```
// You could put anything for the 200 height since you will be changing it in the next line anyway.
[_quoteLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(11, 11, 298, 200];  
[_quoteLabel sizeToFitMultipleLines];
```

Comment: @Inafziger I've confirmed, and Auto Layout is turned off for the entire storyboard, so I'm afraid this isn't it :(

Comment: And what about the springs & struts?  (Autosizing?)

Comment: @Inafziger There are none, at all, it's completely disabled.

Comment: @Inafziger The reason for calling `setFrame` after `sizeToFitMultipleLines` is to re-position it in the center of the view (horizontally) if the resizing caused it to get thinner in width. I've reversed those two lines of code and it's made no difference though, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by using a single `UILabel`, and CoreText with an `NSAttributedString`. Kind of a cop-out, but it works.